# Appending strings with parentheses in a list

Tags: string, list, append

I have a set of strings.

```
people = {'RAM_S', 'SHYAM', 'GEORGEY', 'MUFASSIR'}
```

I have an empty list : `list_c = []`.

I want to append items in `people` to `list_c` such that resulting list looks as follows:

```
list_c = [('RAM_S'),('SHYAM'),('GEORGEY'),('MUFASSIR')]
```

I'm unable to append elements with parentheses in the list.

Please suggest some way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need tuples:

```
result = [tuple([i]) for i in people]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('MUFASSIR',), ('SHYAM',), ('GEORGEY',), ('RAM_S',)]
```

Comment: This is good answer, but is there some way we could remove commas inside each parenthesis?